# is it possible to create immutable object without passing everything in constructor?

Tags: c#

I want to make my class immutable. Obvious way would be to declare all fields as `get; private set;` and to initialize all fields in constructor. So clients must provide everything in constructor. The problem is that when there are ~10 or more fields passing them in constructor become very unreadable, because there are no labels for each field.

For example this is pretty readable:

```
info = new StockInfo
        {
            Name = data[0] as string,
            Status = s,
            LotSize = (int)data[1],
            ISIN = data[2] as string,
            MinStep = (decimal)data[3]
        };
```

compare to this:

```
new StockInfo(data[0] as string, s, (int) data[1], data[2] as string, (decimal) data[3])
```

And now imaging that I have 10 or more parameters.

So how can I make class immutable saving readability?

I can suggest only use the same formatting when using constructor:

```
info = new StockInfo(
            data[0] as string,           // Name
            s,                           // Status
            (int)data[1],                // LotSize
            data[2] as string,           // ISIN
            (decimal)data[3]             // MinStep
       );
```

Can you suggest something better?

Comment: You can always pack some fields to logical group/class and pass that object.

Comment: have you tried using readonly parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Either you have immutable object or you want to have ability to modify object.

1. You can use named parameters.
2. You may consider passing other objects (and group parameters), so that one object will contain only parameters that are somehow very similar.

Looking at your code I may also suggest that you extract parameters first, so instead of passing something like `data[0] as string` you use `string stockName = data[0] as string;` and then use `stockName`. That should make your code more readable.

If you're passing so many parameters to the constructor of your object it may be a good idea to revise your design. You may be violating [Single Responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 9):

Here are some options. You will have to decide what's best for you:

Use a **classic immutable object** (with a massive constructor) with named arguments for readability. (Drawbacks: Some frown on having many constructor arguments. May be inconvenient to use from other .NET languages without support for named arguments.)

```
info = new StockInfo
           (
             name: data[0] as string,
             status: s,
             ...
           )
```

---

Expose the mutable object through an **immutable interface**. (Drawbacks: The object could still be mutated with casting. Extra type to write.)

```
public interface IStockInfo
{
   string Name { get; }
   string Status { get; }
}

IStockInfo info = new StockInfo
                      {
                          Name = data[0] as string,
                          Status = s,
                          ...
                      }
```

---

Expose a **read-only view** of the mutable object - see `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` for example. (Drawbacks: Extra type to implement. Extra object created. Extra indirections.)

```
var readOnlyInfo = new ReadOnlyStockInfoDecorator(info);
```

---

Expose an **immutable clone** of the mutable object. (Drawbacks: Extra type to implement. Extra object created. Copying required.)

```
var immutableInfo = new ImmutableStockInfo(info);
```

---

Use **[freezable objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx)**. (Drawback: Post-freeze mutation-attempts won't be caught until execution-time.)

```
info.Freeze();
info.Name = "Test"; // Make this throw an exception.
```

---

Use **fluent-style builders** or similar (Drawbacks: Some may be unfamiliar with the pattern. Lots of extra code to write. Lots of copies created. Intermediate states may possibly be illegal)

```
info = StockInfo.FromName(data[0] as string)
                .WithStatus(s) // Make this create a modified copy
                .WithXXX() ;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you could do it, using C#'s named parameters:

```
var info = new StockInfo
(
    Name: data[0] as string,
    Status: s,
    LotSize: (int)data[1],
    ISIN: data[2] as string,
    MinStep: (decimal)data[3]
);
```

Comment: You're still passing everything in the constructor, naming parameters are just a nicer way to do so.

Comment: @Mark I'd argue that's not really relevant if you read the question in it's entirety (I know, the title *does* ask for a solution without passing everything in the constructor). The OP makes it pretty clear that his question *really* is `So how can I make class immutable saving readability?` And I think my code snippet should provide a nice illustration to go with Maciek's excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I make class immutable saving readability?

You can use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
info = new StockInfo(
        name: data[0] as string,
        status: s,              
        lotSize: (int)data[1],  
        isin: data[2] as string,
        minStep: (decimal)data[3]
   );
```

Note that the goal of using object initializers is not readability - and they should not be considered a substitute for constructors.  It is a very good idea to always include every parameter in a constructor which is required to properly initialize a type.  Immutable types *must* pass in all of their arguments during construction, either via a constructor or a factory method.

Object initializers will never work with immutable types, as they work by setting values *after* constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Some more possible solutions:

**Immutability by convention**

The object is mutable, you just behave well and never change it after it's been set-up. This is completely inappropriate for most uses (any where the object is public for a start), but can work well for internal "worker" objects with a limited number of places where they are used (and hence a limited number of places where you can mess up and change them).

**Deeper Hierarchy**

Assuming your real class has more than 5 fields (not that hard to read, especially if you've an IDE with tooltips), some may be composable. E.g if you had different parts of a name, and address and a latitude and longitude in the same class, you could break that into name, address and coördinate classes.

A bonus that happens in some such cases, is that if you've many (and I mean **many** for this to be worthwhile, anything less than a few thousand and it's a waste of time) such objects and there are some such fields identical between them, you can sometimes build them in such a way that those shared values have the same object in each case, rather than different identical objects - all the things that can go wrong with aliasing can't happen, since they are immutable after all.

**Builder Classes**

Examples would be `StringBuilder` and `UriBuilder`. Here you've got precisely the issue you have - you want the benefits of immutability, but there are at least some times when you want to be able to construct he object in more than one step.

So you create a different mutable class that has equivalent properties, but with setters as well as getters, along with other mutating methods (whether something like `Append()` makes sense depends on the class of course), and a method that constructs an instance of your immutable class.

I've made use of this with classes whose constructor has as many as 30 parameters, because there really were 30 different pieces of information that was part of the same concern. In this case, about the only place I'd call the constructor was in the corresponding builder class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it may be helpful to have an interface for "maybe-mutable" objects which includes `AsMutable`, `AsNewMutable`, and `AsImmutable` methods.  An immutable object could implelement `AsImmutable` by simply returning itself.  A mutable object should implement `AsImmutable` by returning either a new immutable object created using the mutable one as a constructor parameter, or else an immutable object which is known to be equivalent.  The constructor for the immutable object should load the new object with the contents of the original, but calling `AsImmutable` on all maybe-mutable fields.

A mutable object should simply return itself in response to `AsMutable`, while an immutable object should construct a new "shallowly" mutable object.  If code wishes to mutate an object referred to by a "maybe-mutable" property, it should set the property to its `AsMutable` equivalent.

Calling the `AsNewMutable` method on an immutable object should behave just like `AsMutable`.  Calling it on a mutable object could either behave equivalently to `AsImmutable.AsMutable`, or could create mutable clones of any nested mutable objects (there are times when either approach might be better, depending upon which nested objects will end up being mutated).

If you use this pattern, you should be able to reap many of the benefits of both immutable objects (most notably, the ability to take a snap shot of a "deep" object without needing to make a "deep" copy), and mutable ones (being able to produce an object by performing many steps on the same instance).  Performance may be enhanced by having each a mutable object keep a reference to an immutable object whose state was at some time identical to its own; after constructing an immutable instance, the object could check whether it matches the other and, if so, discard the new instance and return the old one.  While this would seem to represent extra work, it could in fact improve performance considerably in the scenario where a mutable object has `AsImmutable` called upon it more than once between mutations.  If one calls `AsImmutable` twice on a deep tree structure when most of the tree has in fact not been mutated, having the non-mutated parts of the tree return the same object instances both times would facilitate future comparisons.

Note: If one uses this pattern, one should override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for the deeply-immutable type, but not the mutable one.  Immutable objects which hold identical values should be considered interchangeable and thus equivalent, but mutable objects should not be equivalent to anything but themselves regardless of their values.  Note also that some care may be needed if objects hold anything of type `double`, `float`, or `Decimal`, since those types override `Object.Equals` to mean something other than equivalence.

Comment: it's sounds too complicated for my needs. I've just decided to use named parameters in constructor to keep my code relatively simple.